# PostgreSQL extract structure (DDL) without pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, ddl, pg-dump

Is there any option to extract schema structure (DDL) from PostgreSQL buy using standard queries only ?

Im currently using **pg_dump** but Im thinking to develop simple app comparing 2 schemas without need to install anything locally

Comment: You can extract all the information to construct DDL from the `information_schema` views and system tables.  Or you can use the 'Scripts' option on the context menu in pgAdmin to extract the information interactively.

Answer (score 2):

It is not easy.  You can look into the source-code of pg_dump to see how it does it.  It mostly uses standard queries against the catalogs, but it uses an awful lot of them.

There are some functions on the server which help it out, you can view some with:

```
\df *def
```

You could make it a lot simpler if you are willing to cut corners, like only looking at table, indexes(?), and views, rather than all objects.  And only supporting one PostgreSQL version, and ignoring storage parameters, grants, etc.

Comment: i can limit to major objects : views, tables and functions if this can make things easier